# How do I "include" angular-jasmine-matchers in my jasmine-based tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, jasmine

I'm trying to use the `angularjs-jasmine-matchers` extension to the Jasmine framework for testing my angularJs project. According the the [documentation on the project page](https://github.com/ferronrsmith/angularjs-jasmine-matchers), it can be installed using Bower, as follows:

> bower install angularjs-jasmine-matchers --save

I've done that, and the file `matchers.js` has been created somewhere within my `bower-components` folder (within my user profile folder, not actually within my project).

What now? How do I reference that file from my test project? Do I have to copy the file to a particular location?

Comment: I think that this framework is not compatible with jasmine v.2 yet